# Using IEEE floating point standard in math-software.

Tags: math-software, floating-point

For purposes of given math module (that performs some statistical computations) it's sufficient to store reals in IEEE754 floating point format. I'm considering to migrate to SQLLite as persistent storage. But documentation of SQLLite doesn't clearly state what standard it supports.
[SQLLite wiki](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses)  says it supports REAL:

> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

But there are two different IEEE standards for floating-point computation. IEEE 754 (b = 2) and IEEE 854(b = 2 or b = 10). I need to store IEEE 754 single precision float or double in SQLLite column and later read this value into variable with original precision (single or double) in IEEE 754 format (no need any arithmetic).

Two sub-problems appear: one about storing doubles and another about storing single precision values in target unknown 8-byte floating point number.

1. storing doubles: can I be confident that I will read the **same** binary value (754 has unique binary representation), including all kinds of NaN, pos/neg infinity, etc. (in other words: is SQLLite lossless with regard to IEEE754 doubles)?
2. storing single float to double: is this conversion reversible? **This problem is about IEEE754 standard in general and doesn't relate to any specific software**.

---

This question is not only about math-software and SQLLite - it's about representation of floats in different formats and losses related to conversions. Useful introduction article about this topic [here - What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. You may want to ask this on another site, I am not sure which one is best suited though.

Comment: This is a programming question. It probably belongs on stackoverflow but it certainly doesn't belong here.

Comment: SQLLite is hand-written in C (or C++) by one guy, and it uses the file API as database, hence real are C double

Comment: It would be great that they understand this question...

Comment: If you can not deduce it from the source code why not try to set up some run time tests? It might even behave different on different systems.

Comment: @mvw : looking at the source code... are you serious ?

Comment: What is this IEEE?

Comment: IEEE is like ACM but for electrical engineers.

Comment: @mvw : and it is in charge of most of the standards used in networks/internet (wifi, ethernet, probably IP too, etc.)

Comment: Modern compute represent IEEE double as 8 byte binary data. The link you have already state it will store the double as binary data instead of other format that can have conversion error.

Comment: Good for them! :) Never heard of it.

Comment: @Jonas : it is also just the 2nd most famous publication for engineers, after nature/science :)

Comment: Got it, thank you very much @user1952009. I apologize for my ignorance in the matter. Really only a mathematician. :)

Comment: This is my account - if you know how to reassign it to my name - please let me know.

Comment: Thank you - I use stackoverflow usually for questions related to programming. Could you please advise how to rephrase question  - obviously this is math question. The problem that SQLLite wiki does not clearly says what format it uses for real numbers. Otherwise I would not mentioned SQLLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, you have encountered a documentation deficiency in the SQLLite wiki.  They should have specified an 8-byte IEEE floating point number *following the standard of IEEE 754 for double precision numbers*.  This is how all the data bases behave; implementers just assumed that this was the behavior dictated by the standard, and indeed the "standard" writers meant this behavior.

Don't think harshly of the writers of the wiki.  I've been involved in the C++ standard, and OMG it is hard to get everything perfectly right!

But the answer to your real question, concerning NANs and there brethren, is that implementers will have felt free to ignore that issue or invent their own way of comping with division by zero and the like.  So I would not count, for example, on reproducing the NAN you have sent into the database.

Comment: I have to disagree it is a deficiency of SQLLite wiki. Most people who know what an IEEE double is know what it means.

Comment: Confusing: wiki says : SQLite4 does all numeric computations using decimal arithmetic. SQLite4 never uses C datatypes double or float (except in interface routines when converting between double and the internal decimal representation). Instead, all numeric values are represented internally as an 18-digit decimal number with a 3-digit base-10 exponent.

Comment: Probably storing double as decimal is not a loss - article I gave link says: Theorem 15. When a binary IEEE single precision number is converted to the closest eight digit decimal number, it is not always possible to uniquely recover the binary number from the decimal one. However, if nine decimal digits are used, then converting the decimal number to the closest binary number will recover the original floating-point number.

Comment: So probably sufficient number of decimal digits should preserve double - that is recover the same.

Comment: It seems SQLLite doesn't follow the standard of IEEE 754 - they insert NULL instead of NaN.

Comment: And they *certainly* don't preserve the additional info that is embedded into an IEEE-754 NAN.  I believe they don't even distinguish an SNAN (signalling NAN) from a non-signalling NAN.